# How can I track the HTTP requests sent between me and a game server?

Tags: http, ssl, https, server, client

So I was curious as to how I can track the HTTP requests I send to a game as well as the responses? Typically I'd use something like fiddler, but the requests are SSL protected. But since I'm the client, shouldn't there be some way to see what requests I send out and the responses the game gives me back? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup a HTTPS proxy to MiTM (Man in the middle attack) yourself.

Comment: but wouldnt the requests being protected by ssl just prevent that?

Comment: Nope. Mind you, if you’re trying to ´hack’ [sic] a game’s communication with its server, there are many things it can, and probably will do to prevent this type of attack.